# Set focus on Tkinter window (depends on platform?)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, focus

I have a Tkinter program and running it like: `python myWindow.py` starts it all right, but the window is behind the terminal that I use to start it.

Is there a way to make it grab the focus and be the foreground application? Does it depend on the platform?

Comment: The _Related_ sidebar included http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728880/instantiating-a-tkinter-window-without-grabbing-focus which looks potentially useful.

Comment: I would suggest not using Tkinter unless you have to ... IMHO, its a pain.

Comment: Don't let the naysayers fool you. Tkinter is quite useful and easy to use.

Comment: I suppose wxPython is generally better (or so I heard). But what I need is a window with a canvas and lines, circles, rectangles methods, which Tk supports. So Tk being included in Python without additional installations is better (specially since I might share the program with friends). It's just toy programming that I am using it for. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Anyone has better solutions? It's quite a basic requirement for a GUI app to be seen on start. Are we missing some important point?

Comment: Another closely related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892339/make-tkinter-jump-to-the-front

Answer (score 2):

This might be a feature of your particular window manager. One thing to try is for your app to call `focus_force` at startup, after all the widgets have been created.

Comment: Thanks, doesn't work in my case. root.tkraise() at least raises the window above others.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this at the end of your script ?

```
root.iconify()
root.update()
root.deiconify()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat of a combination of various other methods found online, this works on OS X 10.11, and Python 3.5.1 running in a venv, and should work on other platforms too. On OS X, it also targets the app by process id rather than app name.

```
from tkinter import Tk
import os
import subprocess
import platform


def raise_app(root: Tk):
    root.attributes("-topmost", True)
    if platform.system() == 'Darwin':
        tmpl = 'tell application "System Events" to set frontmost of every process whose unix id is {} to true'
        script = tmpl.format(os.getpid())
        output = subprocess.check_call(['/usr/bin/osascript', '-e', script])
    root.after(0, lambda: root.attributes("-topmost", False))
```

You call it right before the `mainloop()` call, like so:

```
raise_app(root)
root.mainloop()
```