# How do I display a matplotlib figure window on top of all other windows in Spyder

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder

I am using the Spyder IDE and I find that matplotlib figure windows always get displayed behind other windows.  For example, immediately after starting Spyder, if I type `plt.plot([0,1],[0,1])` in the console, I get a plot behind the main Spyder window.  How can I make new figure windows display on top off all other windows?

I found this solution ([make matplotlib plotting window pop up as the active one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202228/make-matplotlib-plotting-window-pop-up-as-the-active-one_)), but it does not work for me in Spyder.  I run into trouble with `fig.canvas.manager.window`.  It says `AttributeError: 'FigureManagerMac' object has no attribute 'window'`.

Comment: Had the same issue. Here is the solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/32934536/5406821

Comment: Looks like you need to set your SpyderPrefs to use Qt4Agg or some other non-MacOS backend for matplotlib.  Works for me after doing this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, I happened upon the solution when I was working on something else.

When I use the `MacOSX` backend, then `fig.canvas.manager.window` gives `AttributeError: 'FigureManagerMac' object has no attribute 'window'`.  However, when I use the `TkAgg` backend, then `fig.canvas.manager` has the attribute `window`.  Thus, I can implement [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892339/make-tkinter-jump-to-the-front) as follows:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot([0,1],[0,1])
#Put figure window on top of all other windows
fig.canvas.manager.window.attributes('-topmost', 1)
#After placing figure window on top, allow other windows to be on top of it later
fig.canvas.manager.window.attributes('-topmost', 0)
```

Simple enough, right?  The first tricky part is you must set the backend before you import pyplot. Changing the backend afterwards does nothing in my experience.  The second tricky part is Spyder's Scientific Startup script does `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` right when you launch the Spyder IDE, so you have no chance to set the backend before pyplot is imported.  The way around this is go to Preferences->Console->External Modules, set the GUI Backend to TkAgg, and restart Spyder. Then the code above works properly.

Previously I was setting the backend via `matplotlib.rcParams['backend'] = 'TkAgg'` right after launching Spyder.  When I was doing something else, however, I started getting errors that mentioned the `MacOSX` backend.  This did not make any sense to me, since I thought I was using `TkAgg`.  The maddening part is when I queried `matplotlib.get_backend` it returned `TkAgg`!  Apparently, setting the backend after importing pyplot acts as if you have changed the backend, but it does not actually change the backend.  Argg!!

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) I'm glad you figured out by yourself how to fix your problem. I have some words about `matplotlib` backends: on Mac we decided to set it to `MacOSX` irrespective of user preferences because it's the most reliable one, but given your confusion, I think we need to revisit this decision. I'll do it for our upcoming 2.3 release :)