# Matplotlib plots always hiding in background in MacOS

Tags: eclipse, macos, matplotlib, pycharm

Whenever I show a matplotlib plot, it opens in the background, and I actually have to move around my IDE window to find it (It doesn't show up on Command-Tab).  If the IDE (PyCharm or Eclipse) is in full-screen, it doesn't show up with "exploded window view" Fn-F3 either.  It's really annoying to have to move around windows every time I want to see a plot.  I'm not sure if this is the fault of matplotlib or OSX.

Desired behaviour is that once the command plt.show() is executed, the plot window pops up to the front.  Or at a minimum can be Command-Tab'ed to.

Anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Matplotlib is aware of this issue and provides a work-around: https://matplotlib.org/faq/osx_framework.html

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate of: 
[make matplotlib plotting window pop up as the active one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202228/make-matplotlib-plotting-window-pop-up-as-the-active-one)

I'm leaving it open because my original searches did not take me to that question.