# python images not appearing on top

Tags: python, matplotlib, show

**How can I get images/python windows to appear on top when I run a python script?**

I'm using python/anaconda (2.7.10,2.3.0) on osx 10.x and trying to do rapid development on an image processing project.  I'm using matplotlib and opencv.  Every time I render an image/figure, it does not appear on top and I have to cmd-tab all the way to the end to get to it, causing major headaches; I'd like to know how to fix this.  Bonus points if you can give me pointers on a stable python installation for image processing (getting some funny conflicts with opencv library...)

Things I've tried:

- show()
- **changing the backend (I've tried PDF, Qt4Agg, Qt5Agg, TkAgg, GTKCairo...)**
- updating anaconda/python packages

So... what are my options?  Framework installation?  Choose some other back end?  I get the feeling there must be some setting somewhere that I'm missing, since my friend has a near identical setup without this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [make matplotlib plotting window pop up as the active one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202228/make-matplotlib-plotting-window-pop-up-as-the-active-one)

Comment: @Maikflow no.  Please read the question.  I directly say that I have already tried several backends.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate.  Rather, trying the fixes suggested elsewhere did not work for me!