# How to bring Tkinter window in front of other windows?

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

I'm working with some Tkinter Python code (Python 3.4), and I've come across a problem. When I create my Tkinter window it doesn't show up in front. I do it currently with the following code:

```
from tkinter import *
win = Tk()
win.minsize(width=1440, height=828)
win.maxsize(width=1440, height=828)
```

The `minsize()` and `maxsize()` make the window cover my entire screen, but the original python running window (The one that would`print("Hello, World!")`) ends up on top. Is there a way to fix this? I'm running OS X 10.10.1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a window jump to the front?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892339/how-to-make-a-window-jump-to-the-front)

Comment: Calling lift() and attributes() doesn't put the window top-most in my case: * macOS 10.12.5
* Python 3.6.1 installed through Homebrew And I found this answer work in my case: * https://stackoverflow.com/a/37235492/2708288

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set it as the *topmost* (but it will always stay in front of the others):

```
win.attributes('-topmost', True) # note - before topmost
```

To not make it *always* in front of the others, insert this code before the mainloop:

```
win.lift()
win.attributes('-topmost', True)
win.attributes('-topmost', False)
```

Don't forget `win.mainloop()` at the end of your code (even if in some cases it's not explicitly required)

Other discussions on the same problem:

- [How to put a Tkinter window on top of the others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691655/how-to-put-a-tkinter-window-on-top-of-the-others)
- [How to make a Tkinter window jump to the front?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892339/make-tkinter-jump-to-the-front)