# tkinter messagebox always appears behind main pygame window

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

I am trying to make my messagebox appear in front of my `pygame` window, but it keeps appearing behind it. Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import messagebox

# pygame loop here
messagebox.showinfo("Title", "Message here")
```

Do I need to do add some lines of code to bring it to the front? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [How to put a Tkinter window on top of the others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691655/how-to-put-a-tkinter-window-on-top-of-the-others)

Comment: I tried making a `Tk()` object and using the `lift()` function, but it still appears behind the window.

Comment: @m.o Please post the full code.

Comment: you can also try second answer - with `'-topmost'` but you may have to create own window with message.

Comment: BTW: `tkinter` to work correctly may need `mainloop()`

Comment: Got it to work. Posted the answer. Though not entirely sure why it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it to work. I had to add `root.withdraw()` as well.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

# pygame loop here
messagebox.showinfo("Title", "Message here")
root.lift()
```

Not sure why hiding the root tkinter window makes it work...

Comment: The old programing problem: "What does this line do?" "Not sure, but if you delete it, it doesn't work"

Answer (score 0):

This will put the window in the middle of the screen on the top level of everything, so it will not be hidden behind and stays in front.

```
window = Tk()
window.eval('tk::PlaceWindow %s center' % window.winfo_toplevel())
```