# I have made a tkinter program that displays the time and i want it to stay on screen even if I change tabs is there any way of making thi s

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, tabs

I have made a Tkinter program in Python that displays the time and I want it to stay on screen even if I change tabs is there any way of doing this

Comment: Do you mean you want to keep the tkinter window on top?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to put a tkinter window on top of the others?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691655/how-to-put-a-tkinter-window-on-top-of-the-others)

Comment: [What if two programs did this?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050607-00/?p=35413)

Comment: Your questions is a copy of your title lacking detail and code. Please update your question to include example code and exactly what you need. IE Do you mean tabs within tkinter or tabbing applications within windows?

Comment: What I meant was like the taskbar which stays on screen no matter which tab you are in. Thanks to DapperDuck for his anwser it really helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `-topmost` attribute. Here is the code:

```
root.attributes("-topmost", True)
```

Here is an example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

tk.Label(root, text="Test").pack()

root.attributes("-topmost", True)
root.mainloop()
```