# Bring a tkinter on vlc window to the foreground

Tags: python, tkinter, window, vlc, foreground

Lets describe my problem :
Im making a vlc media player and i have a problem, i cant find how to put in foreground my tkinter button
I put vlc in full screen but my tkitner command stay in the background
how can i put in in front like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPt5w.jpg)
I'm a beginner and i'm lost can semeone help me a little pls !
(sorry for my english it's not my native langage)

```
from tkinter import *
import vlc

player = vlc.MediaPlayer("G:/Films/21 Jump Street.mkv")
player.play()
player.toggle_fullscreen()

Fenetre = Tk()

def pause():
    player.stop()
     
 
Fenetre.geometry('300x50+0+980')
#Fenetre.overrideredirect(1) #Remove border
ok = Button(Fenetre, text="Stop", command=pause)
ok.pack()

Fenetre.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you tried: `<tkinter.Tk>.attributes("-topmost", True)`?

Comment: omg ty ! it works you're the best

Comment: You might also want to look at `<tkinter.Tk>.overrideredirect(True)` to remove the title bar for the window. But hiding the window will be tricky.

Comment: Answers almost certainly lie here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691655/how-to-put-a-tkinter-window-on-top-of-the-others

Comment: I'm french when i'm typing in english i don't have the same result with google btw to both :) it help me a lot