# UNIX - Tkinter Window always in the first plan

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make Tkinter jump to the front](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892339/make-tkinter-jump-to-the-front)

I am seeking a solution to put in front plan a Tkinter Window ... But when I launch other programs, they come in first plan, hiding my window.

It's just about creating a Window that gonna be put always in the first plan

I've tried some tricks but nothing works ! Thx !

EDIT:

```
from Tkinter import *

def quit():
    fen = Toplevel(root)
    fen.grab_set()
    fen.focus_set()
    b = Button(fen, text = "Ok", command = root.quit).pack()

root = Tk()
bouton = Button(root, text = "Quit", command=quit).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

But not working ...

Comment: "I've tried some tricks, but nothing works"  -- What tricks have you tried?

Comment: When you say "front plan" do you mean "front *plane*" (ie: it should be above all other windows)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `topmost` parmameter to `wm_attributes`. For example:

```
fen.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
```

This may not work on all platforms; it's somewhat dependent on the window manager you're using.

Comment: Thank you very much ! That's exactly what I was looking for ! Works like a charm on my OS X !