# Can´t get Focus on Python Tkinter Window

Tags: python, tkinter

I am Programing a small Program in Tkinter and wanted to have two windows open. Then i wanted to bring one Window in front. Program Code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("ROOT")

new = Tk()
new.title("NEW")
new.lift()

root.mainloop()
new.lift()

new.mainloop()

new.lift()
```

What did i did wrong with new.lift? New dosn´t come to front :(
Does someone know how to bring a Window in front and give the Window focus?

Comment: Helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892339/make-tkinter-jump-to-the-front

Comment: I have some problems with new.lift(). scroll up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you can't have two instances of `Tk` at the same time, and you can't have two `mainloop`s running at the same time.

To create more than one window use `Topolevel`,

```
new = Toplevel(root)
```

Do not call `mainloop` a second time, it's unnecessary. Also, don't put any executable code after the call to `mainloop` because `mainloop` won't return until the main window has been destroyed.