# Make Python GUI Active

Tags: python, tkinter

Here is some simplified code. Let's just say that, for reasons not relevant to this example, I want to make the root window active, not just on top.

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()


def wake():
    time.sleep(3)
    root.attributes("-topmost", True)
    root.attributes("-topmost", FALSE)

button = Button(root, text='Bring Forth!', command=wake)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

When you press the button and go to another application, it reappears on top, but not "active", like the "tk" title and menu buttons are gray until you click somewhere on the GUI. I know it seems weird, but it would be very helpful. Thank you

Comment: Which platform are you talking about? Windows? MacOS X? Something else? Tkinter apps seem to have a hard time activating with MacOS X, so people use workarounds like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32121848/39223

Comment: Have you tried `w.focus_force()`. Check [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html).

Comment: I'm running a Windows platform. I tried root.focus_force(), but it didn't seem to do anything, though the description seemed to match what I was trying to do. I also tried root.grab_set_global further down the list, but with no luck :(

Comment: Interestingly, when I call grab_set in OS X, the icon bounces up and down. I assume this does something on Windows?

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with OS X. Do you mean the icon in the top left? Because it doesn't appear to do anything on Windows.

Comment: No. There is a dock at the bottom of the screen with app icons and it bounces on that.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `root.grab_set()` then `root.focus()` like this:

```
def wake():
    time.sleep(3)
    root.attributes("-topmost", True)
    root.grab_set()
    root.focus()
    root.attributes("-topmost", FALSE)
```

It works on windows 7 Professional..