# tkinter: Frame in Toplevel displayed in parent

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have currently two problems with Toplevel instances in Tkinter.

First and most important: I want to display a popup window and place 2 frames in it for better arangement in grid, but it doesn't work as I expect it to work:

```
import tkinter


root = tkinter.Tk()
tkinter.Button(root, text="ABC").grid(column=0, row=0)
tkinter.Label(root, text="FOO").grid(column=1, row=1)

win = tkinter.Toplevel()
f1 = tkinter.Frame(win).grid(row=0, column=0)
f2 = tkinter.Frame(win).grid(row=1, column=1)
tkinter.Label(f1, text="FRAME 1").grid()
tkinter.Label(f2, text="FRAME 2").grid()

root.mainloop()
```

I would expect "FRAME 1" and "FRAME 2" to be placed in the Toplevel window, but they are actually placed in `root`. How do I fix this?

Second, less important: The popup window in the code above is spawning behind the root window, while I would like it to be placed in front of `root`, how do I achieve this?

Comment: For moving the window to the top maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892339/how-to-make-a-tkinter-window-jump-to-the-front) will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When setting your geometry manager be it `grid()`, `pack()` or `place()` and you need to be able to interact with that widget later you will need to assign the widget to a variable and then apply the geometry manager on a new line using that variable name. This way your variable will not be a value of `None` but rather the proper widget. This happens because the geometry managers all return `None`.

Next the reason your labels are on the wrong windows is because when your labels try to connect with `f1` and `f2` they are not able to find a proper tkinter container due to the values being `None` so it defaults to the root tkinter window in an attempt to be place on something.

With fixing the `None` issues you will also fix your label issue.

To address the matter of your top level window not being in front of your root window there are a couple of things you can do. The main reason this is happening is how your code is generating the top level at `__init__` rather than later with a button or a timed event.

If you really need your top level window to open at the same time as root you can use `after()` and a function to do this and it will be placed on top. If you do not need it right when the window opens you may want to assign a command to a button to run a function that builds the top window.

Here is an example with `after()`:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()

def create_top():
    win = tk.Toplevel(root)
    f1 = tk.Frame(win)
    f1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    f2 = tk.Frame(win)
    f2.grid(row=1, column=1)
    tk.Label(f1, text="FRAME 1").grid()
    tk.Label(f2, text="FRAME 2").grid()

tk.Button(root, text="ABC").grid(column=0, row=0)
tk.Label(root, text="FOO").grid(column=1, row=1)

root.after(10, create_top)
root.mainloop()
```

Here is an example with a button:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()

def create_top():
    win = tk.Toplevel(root)
    f1 = tk.Frame(win)
    f1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    f2 = tk.Frame(win)
    f2.grid(row=1, column=1)
    tk.Label(f1, text="FRAME 1").grid()
    tk.Label(f2, text="FRAME 2").grid()

tk.Button(root, text="ABC", command=create_top).grid(column=0, row=0)
tk.Label(root, text="FOO").grid(column=1, row=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

You set your frames `f1` and `f2` to the return-value of the `grid()` command, which is `None`, therefore `tkinter.Label(f1, text="FRAME 1").grid()` does not work as you expect.

Try something like this:

```
win = tkinter.Toplevel()
f1 = tkinter.Frame(win)
f1.grid(row=0, column=0)
tkinter.Label(f1, text="FRAME 1").grid()
```