# Draw a GUI that overrides another GUI in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I am writing a GUI with the screen of Raspberry.Each time I destroy a GUI and call a new GUI there will be a delay of about a few seconds to make the user see the raspberry's desktop. I want to draw a loading interface down to the background so that when I switch the screen the user won't see the raspberry desktop. I use this code:

```py
from tkinter import *

class Load_Screen:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.configure(background='white')
        self.frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.frame.pack()

        self.canvas = Canvas(self.frame, width = 350, height = 250)
        self.canvas.configure(background='white')
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.img = PhotoImage(file="image/loading.png")
        self.canvas.create_image(55,150, anchor=W, image=self.img)

        newWindow = Toplevel(self.master)
        newWindow.geometry("700x500")
        app = Main_Screen(newWindow)

class Main_Screen:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.frame.pack()

def main(): 
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("760x600")
    app = Load_Screen(root)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

However, the loading screen overrides the main screen. And I want the opposite, the bottom loading screen and the main screen above

Comment: don't destroy GUI - replace items in the same window. You can use `Frame` to create screens and replace them in main window `Tk`

Comment: Thanks. I will do this when I can make the Tk window display override the Toplevel window

Comment: replacing `Frame` in window it will always hide desktop and you will no need `Toplevel` window.

Comment: [How to make a Tkinter window jump to the front?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892339/how-to-make-a-tkinter-window-jump-to-the-front)

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution which i have found at
[How to make a Tkinter window jump to the front?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892339/how-to-make-a-tkinter-window-jump-to-the-front)

```py
from tkinter import *

class Load_Screen:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.configure(background='white')
        self.frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.frame.pack()

        self.canvas = Canvas(self.frame, width = 350, height = 250)
        self.canvas.configure(background='white')
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.img = PhotoImage(file="image/loading.png")
        self.canvas.create_image(55,150, anchor=W, image=self.img)

        newWindow = Toplevel(self.master)
        newWindow.geometry("700x500")
        app = Main_Screen(newWindow)

class Main_Screen:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.frame.pack()

def main(): 
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("760x600")
    root.lift()
    app = Load_Screen(root)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Use root.lift() make Load_Screen below Main_Screen