# Hide tk window when using filedialog

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to use `filedialog.asksavefilename` to get a save file path. I am running this code in the IDLE shell and it's a text based interface. This is the function to get the save path:

```
def getPath():
    root=tk.Tk()
    root.lift()
    root.attributes('-topmost',True)
    root.after_idle(root.attributes,'-topmost',False)
    path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".txt", filetypes=(("Text Documents", "*.txt"),))
    root.destroy()
```

The dialog opened behind other windows, so I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36191443) to make the dialog appear at the front. This works, but there is still an empty window behind it which I don't want. I've tried using `root.withdraw()` but this just hides everything. I'd like to have only the file dialog open without the empty tk window. Any ideas as to how to do this?

Comment: did you end up figuring out how to get rid of that window?

Comment: @oldboy I'd completely forgotten about this question, I had a look and worked out how to do it. Hope this helps!

Comment: found out that `Tk().withdraw()` does the trick! thanks nonetheless @henry <3

Comment: That's odd, it didn't work for me

Comment: `TK().widthdraw(); filedialog.askopenfilename()` is working for me. Which version of Python and which OS you using?

Comment: Windows 10, python 3.8

Comment: hm i was on windows 10 too and i believe python 3.9x. maybe that is why?

Comment: Yeah, thanks for reminding of this question, I'm glad I found something that works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a way to achieve the desired effect:

```
def getPath():
    root=tk.Tk()
    root.overrideredirect(True)
    root.attributes("-alpha", 0)
    path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".txt", filetypes=(("Text Documents", "*.txt"),))
    root.destroy()
```

I've removed all of the unnecessary `lift` and `topmost` parts - they didn't help. I used `root.overrideredirect(True)` to remove the title bar and `root.attributes("-alpha", 0)` to make the window 100% transparent, so you can't see it. The only drawback is that the file dialog window flashes when it opens, but that's not too much of a problem.

Comment: This seems hacky, but the advantage is that by leaving out `root.overrideredirect(True)`, the file dialog is represented in the task bar. (Unlike solutions that use `tkinter.Tk().withdraw()`)

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same requirement i.e. using some of the tkinter.filedialog functions from console apps or scripts rather than a GUI. All my searches for how to achieve it turned up answers involving the creation of a temporary tkinter root window and destroying it after using the dialog box. For years I used such a solution, but was always annoyed at the lag that it created (sometimes, randomly, quite long).

I recently discovered that you just have to invoke the dialog box function - no pesky root window required!

```
from tkinter import filedialog

def getPath(): # now barely worth writing as a function!
    path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".txt", filetypes=(("Text Documents", "*.txt"),))
    return path

print(getPath())
```

This has been working for me with filedialog.askopenfilename, filedialog.askdirectory etc, and without the annoying lag. If only I had seen an answer like this earlier!

Please comment if it does not work on your system/version though.

Answer (score -1):

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename


def get_path():
    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    path = asksaveasfilename()
    root.destroy()
    return(path)





print(get_path()) # to verify expected result
```

Is this the behavior you're looking for? Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've tried this, but using `root.withdraw` causes the file dialog to not appear

Comment: @Henry For me, it does appear.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it hides the file dialog from the task bar. If other windows are in front of the file dialog, you have to minimize each of those windows one by one, or look for the file dialog in the Task View rather than task bar.