# Why won't Toplevel window remain on top?

Tags: toplevel

Python 3.8 tkinter 8.6  Following code creates a child window, but the child is covered by the root window. Why isn't the Toplevel on top ? Tried all 3 geometry managers with no success. Even *takefocus* doesn't help. The child appears first and is covered by root.
'''
from tkinter import *

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry("900x600")
root.title(" Root window with Toplevel as child") 

achild = Toplevel(root, takefocus = True )  
achild.geometry("300x200+300+200")  
achild.title("This is window named achild")

def main() :    
    mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    main()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a Tkinter window jump to the front?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892339/how-to-make-a-tkinter-window-jump-to-the-front)

Answer (score 1):

Use the lift method to keep `achild` above root window:

```py
achild.lift()
```

The following will keep `achild` window above other windows (including non-Tk windows):

```py
achild.attributes("-topmost", True)
```

Comment: achild.attributes("-topmost", True)  succeeds in placing it on top.

Comment: achild.lift()  did not work in my code.