# how can i make tkinter window come to front

Tags: python, tkinter

when i try disappearing tkinter window with `Tk.withdraw`

and then i take it back by `Tk.wm_iconify` it goes to last layer but i want it to be in the front
any help would be appreciate

Comment: no i've already found this but not worked

Comment: Saying that "its not working" is very vague. Update your question with a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with `root.deiconify` and `root.lift()` where `root` is your main window, the instance of `Tk()`

Comment: tried it but not worked

Comment: What operating system are you using? I think Mac OS may behave slightly differently from Windows. *Edit*: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8775078/8512262) for a possible Mac solution

Comment: @kkmmp without some basic code to test we will have to guess at your needs. Please provided an example.