# Is there a raise function in customtkinter?

Tags: python, customtkinter

Is there a raise function in the customtkinter library that is the equivalent to 'tkraise()' in normal tkinter? I'm not sure if I'm being stupid but I have looked at documentation and different sites and I haven't found an answer, can anyone help?

I initially assumed that it was 'ctkraise' or 'CTkraise()' but it is neither, additionally, it is not tkraise either.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting such a function to *do*?

Comment: To raise a frame on top of a stack of all of the frames

Comment: Does the Tkinter [`lift`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892339) work?