# Python tkinter show window on current active screen where script is executed

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

currently I have 2 screens, where I program and run my script on not main one.
While I run my script with tkinter gui it pops up on that main one, not active one.
Is there any possibility to force tkinter gui to pop on screen where script is actually executed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a Tkinter window jump to the front?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892339/how-to-make-a-tkinter-window-jump-to-the-front)

Comment: @toyotaSupra unfortunately no, what you provided only assure that new tkinter window always pop up on front of the screen, I have already tried that. I also tried to center my windows to be at exact center of the screen, but I can't find any solution to open tkinter window on current active screen where user runs script. It always pop up on main screen which is marked as main by OS.