# How to Make macOS Alert Pop-Up Over Other Applications?

Tags: python, macos, user-interface, tkinter

I am attempting to create an alert system for myself using the following code. I have an external backend that triggers this alert. My goal is to have the alert message box, or whatever is possible, to pop up and become the main screen, even when I am using another application on macOS. I haven't yet considered Windows compatibility, but here's what I've tried so far:

`main.py`:

```py
import time
import alert  # Import the alert module

def main():
    # Here you can dynamically set the alert message
    alert_message = "You have received an alert!\n\n[Dummy] Internal Error Occurred at 963"

    # Wait for 5 seconds before showing the alert
    time.sleep(5)
    alert.show_alert(alert_message)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`alert.py`:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import pygame

def play_sound():
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load("notification.mp3")
    pygame.mixer.music.play()

def show_alert(message):
    play_sound()
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()

    # Load and set the custom icon
    icon = tk.PhotoImage(file='logo.png')
    root.iconphoto(False, icon)

    # Display the message box with confirmation buttons
    response = messagebox.askokcancel("Alert", message)

    if response:
        print("Confirmed")
    else:
        print("Declined")

    root.destroy()
```

The code does pop up the alert, but it appears in the background. For example, if my terminal is maximized and I trigger the alert from the terminal, I will only hear the sound but won't see the notification. I want the notification to take control of the screen even when I'm using another window. Do you have any suggestions or input on how to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a Tkinter window jump to the front?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892339/how-to-make-a-tkinter-window-jump-to-the-front)

Comment: @JonSG No, I believe it what does the trick for windows, for MacOS I tried and it didn't work

Comment: Sorry, there are a bunch of  "if you are on a Mac" answer lower in that thread that might help. Seems like they start at about: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8775078/218663 Hopefully one of the Mac suggestions helps.

Comment: @Akon. Does this link help? https://medium.com/@uditvashisht/how-to-create-a-macos-compatible-pop-up-window-in-tkinter-the-right-way-704053e34871

Comment: @toyotaSupra No, I took the entire code, and his example doesn't function correctly. The pop-up doesn't appear at all.